# Prove if $X$ is an integrable errv, then $X\geq 0$ a.s iff $\int_{A} XdP\geq 0$

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying to prove this question:

If $X$ is an integrable errv then $X\geq 0$ a.s iff $\forall A\in \Omega$, $\int_{A} XdP\geq 0$

Can you give me any hint to construct a proof? I know that $E(X)=\int_{A} XdP +\int_{A^c} XdP$ and $\int_{A} XdP = \int \mathbb{1}_A XdP$
Do I have to use those equation, or am i wrong?

Comment: From left to right it is obvious. For right to left: take $A=\{\omega: X(\omega)<0\}$ and consider $\int_A$.

Comment: If $X\geq 0$ then the term $\int 1_{A}XdP\geq 0$ is obvious right? But the left side, can you give me more hints?

Comment: Right. What can you say about $\int_A X\, dP$ for $A=\{\omega: X(\omega <0\}$?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\mathbb E[|X|]<\infty$. If $\mathbb P(X\geqslant 0)=1$, then for any $A\in\Omega$ we have
$$
\mathbb E[X\mathsf 1_A] = \mathbb E\left[X\mathsf 1_A\mathsf 1_{\{X\geqslant 0\}}\right] + \mathbb E\left[X\mathsf 1_A\mathsf 1_{\{X< 0\}}\right] = \mathbb E\left[X\mathsf 1_A\mathsf 1_{\{X\geqslant 0\}}\right] \geqslant 0,
$$
since $\mathbb E\left[\mathsf 1_{\{X>0\}}\right]=\mathbb P(X<0)=0$ and the expectation of a nonnegative random variable is nonnegative. This follows from the Lebesgue integral of a nonnegative measurable function being nonnegative.

Conversely, suppose that $\mathbb E\left[X\mathsf 1_A\right]\geqslant 0$ for all $A\in\Omega$. Then in particular $\mathbb E\left[X\mathsf 1_{\{X<0\}} \right]\geqslant 0$. This implies that $\mathbb P(X\geqslant 0)=1$.